# Closed Nowhere dense is frentier of an open set

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification, open-problem

Excuse me can you see this question 
Every closed nowhere dense set is the frontier of an open set ...

I tried on it but i am not sure , 
I prove it as follows
Let $A$ is closed nowhere dense set, take the open set $X\setminus A$ ..

Claim.. $\operatorname{Fr}(X\setminus A)=A$

$\operatorname{Fr}(X\setminus A) = \operatorname{Fr}(A)$ but $\operatorname{Fr}(A) \subseteq A$, since $A$ is closed so $\operatorname{Fr}(X\setminus A) \subseteq A$

To prove that $A \subseteq\operatorname{Fr}(X\setminus A)$
Let $x\in A$ s.t $A$ is closed nowhere dense , let $U(x,\epsilon)$ implies $U(x,\epsilon)\cap A \ne\varnothing$ .. but $U(x,\epsilon) =\varnothing$ since $A$ is nowhere dense Which is contradiction ($x \in U(x,\epsilon)$) so $U(x,\epsilon)\cap (X\setminus A)\ne\varnothing$ thus $x \in \operatorname{Fr}(X\setminus A)$ thus $A \subseteq \operatorname{Fr}(X\setminus A)$

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

The first part is okay. I think that you have the right idea for the second part, but what you’ve written is very hard to follow and partly wrong. In particular, there is no reason to think that $X$ is a metric space, so you can’t use $\epsilon$-balls. Fortunately, you don’t need them: open nbhds of any kind will do. Let $x\in A$, and let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$. $A$ has empty interior, so $U\nsubseteq A$, and therefore $U\cap(X\setminus A)\ne\varnothing$. $U$ was an arbitrary open nbhd of $x$, so $x\in\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$, and therefore $x\in\operatorname{Fr}(X\setminus A)$.

Comment: for the open set (i.e) the frontier of an open set is closed and nowhere dense , i prove it as follow/ let E subset of X , E is open set in X . Fr(E)=closure of F intersection with closure of (X/E) which is closed . Assume by contrary that Fr(E) not nowhere dense so there exist U open set not empty s.t U subset of closure for Fr(E) = Fr(E) , let x belong to U implies x belongs to interior of Fr(E) implies x belong interior of E closure and interior of X/E. Closure thus x belong interior of E closure and x belong to interior of (X/E) = X/Eclosure thus contradiction so Fr(E) is nowhere dense